# Adding Groovy Tests to Java Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have been using Jsoup in my Groovy scripts to parse html pages. The script includes the Jsoup library by using grapes.

However, I ran into a bug and wanted to fix it. I was able to repeat the bug within the Groovy script. I tried to replicate the bug by adding a Java test to the project, however the test passed and I wasn't able to get any useful information.

I want to replicate the bug within the project by writing a tests in Groovy. However, I'm not sure what changes I need to make to `pom.xml` in order to include and run Groovy tests. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used was to include [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) into the project. The first step involves making the necessary changes to `pom.xml`. So add the following to the `<plugins>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>addSources</goal>
                <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <!-- if including source jars, use the no-fork goals
       otherwise both the Groovy sources and Java stub sources will get included in your jar -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- source plugin \> = 2.1 is required to use the no-fork goals -->
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Next add the following to the `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Next all create the appropriate test directory and test class:

```
mkdir src/test/groovy
mkdir -p src/test/groovy/org/jsoup/integration
touch src/test/groovy/org/jsoup/integration/GroovyTest.groovy
```

Then I added tests to `GroovyTest.groovy` and I was able to execute the tests.